# Undefined array key "hide_connection_errors"

Tags: phpmyadmin, version, sonarqube5.1.2

The error message encountered by the phpMyAdmin version 5.1.2 of the xampp-windows-x64-8.1.1-2-VS16-installer below, is there any related solution?!

[screenshot of error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uBM16.png)

Comment: Please include error messages as text rather than as an image; it helps when others search for the same problem and saves those of us who try to answer the questions from needing to click through another link unnecessarily.

Answer (score 2):

Try to apply changes from the following commit or wait for the next phpMyAdmin version.

[fix 'Undefined array key "hide_connection_errors"'](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/pull/17304/commits/b2fa57efa66e23de2b0c1bce63ae5dd9fdb3f262)

Comment: This is correct, phpMyAdmin 5.1.3 will be released shortly to address this problem. Related bug report: https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/17307